# I am now studying about android which first I creating edit text and when fresh the button edit to integer

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I'm using android studio to build new App.I created action of Button. Below is the code snippet.

```
final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            int myNum = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
                        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

When I'm trying to run the module, it give this error message.

[image]
What is this error message? I can't understand this.

Comment: The error message is telling you the App has crashed. Probably because you are calling findViewById before your layout is inflated, so the object is invalid

Comment: Did you check the error stackstrace ? Check your log and paste the error here.

Answer (score 1):

```
final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
```

put the above lines just after these lines

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

i.e,

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
```

Otherwise your Activity cannot find the view with id 'editText' and 'addButton'.
By calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), you are saying your activity  that, activity_main is the layout for your activity and all the views you are referring is from this layout.